# How to make link not change color after visited?

Tags: css

I have this css:

```css
a:visited 
{
    text-decoration: none;
    decoration: none; 
}
```

After a link is visited it changes color.

It is happening to the "Browse All Problems" link on the bottom of the right side of this page: http://www.problemio.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Text decoration affects the underline, not the color.

To set the visited color to the same as the default, try:

```css
a { 
    color: blue;
}
```

Or

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    color: blue;
}

a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: This code does not stop a link from changing color, it forces it to be a known same color.  Does not work if you don't know what the color will be and just want the link to ignore visits.

Answer (score 58):

In order to avoid duplicate *code*, I recommend you to define the color once, for both states:

```
a, a:visited{
     color: /* some color */;
}
```

This, indeeed, will mantain your `<a>` color (whatever this color is) even when the link has been visited.

**Notice that,** if the color of the element inside of the `<a>` is being inherited (e.g. the color is set in the `body`), you could do the following trick:

```
a, a:visited {
    color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: but what does the inhert inherit from?  The nearest outside element?  It messed up the right side links now :)

Comment: No, it's not. Inherit doesn't inherit the color of <a>; it inherits the color of the parent element. This will produce completely unexpected results. See this pen: http://codepen.io/mattstauffer/pen/yvnfc

Answer (score 8):

Simply give it a css color

like :

```
a
{
 color:red;
}
```

Comment: I have been using `a, a:visited { color: red; }` for a long time, but I'm thinking of just going with `a { color: red; }` from here out. It seems to work to override both the browser default a:link and a:visited just fine. If you define :visited once then you have to do it again every time you get more specific, `.my_class aside a, .my_class aside a:visited {}` etc...

Answer (score 4):

**For application on all the anchor tags, use**

CSS

```
a:visited{
    color:blue;
}
```

**For application on only some of the anchor tags, use**

CSS

```
.linkcolor a:visited{
    color:blue;
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="linkcolor"><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">Go to Home</a></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use a diferent class:

like

```
.clase
{
text-decoration-color: none;
color: #682864;
text-decoration: none;

}
.clase2:hover
{
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}

 <a href="#" class="clase2 clase"> link que no tiene subrayado ni color standar</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
a, a:visited { 
    color:red; text-decoration:none; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set to a new color or prevent the change of the color of a specific link *after* visiting it, add inside the  tag of that link:

```
<a style="text-decoration:none; color:#ff0000;" href="link.html">test link</a>
```

Above the color is #ff0000 but you can make it anything you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

```
a:visited
{
color: #881033;
}
```

(or whatever color you want it to be)

`text-decoration` is for underlining(overlining etc.
`decoration` ist not a valid css rule.

Answer (score 1):

```
(Header CSS:)

<style>

a  {   
   color: #ccc;   /* original colour state*/
}

a:active {
   color: #F66;  
}


a[tabindex]:focus {
    color: #F66;
    outline: none;
}

</style>


(Body HTML:)

<a href="javascript:;" style="font-size:36px; text-decoration:none;"  tabindex="1">click me &#9829;</a>
```