# How to display unvisted url to a user

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I want to display url stored url in my data base.if the user has visited the link he will be not shown the url or the url colour will be changed for the specific user.
my css code to change colour of visited link are

```html
<html>
<style>
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: green;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: red;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: red;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: yellow;
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Mouse over and click the link: <a href="www.stackoverflow">name</a></p>

</body>
 </html>
```

and my php code to display name and the name will be linked to the url and url wil not b displayed;-

```html
<?php

mysql_connect('mysql', 'user', 'pass');
mysql_select_db('add');
$query =mysql_query('select * from addimage');

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
{

echo '<div style="min-width:180px;height:40px;border:gray 1px;float:left;">'.$row['url']. '</div>';
}

?>
```

I want only the name to be displayed on webpage and name will be linked to name in same field to url.and when the user clicks the link the clour of link should b displayed or the name should not be shown again to  the same user

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make link not change color after visited?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188060/how-to-make-link-not-change-color-after-visited)

Comment: I know you have done everything you can to make this question clear. The snippets are OK, and the problem exists. But I still don't understand it. Please, try to write few more explanation paragraphs. It should be really helpful for everyone. +1 from me.

Comment: I agree with @JacekKowalewski I've read it three or four times and I can't seem to grasp if this is just a simple css issue or if you are wanting to do something a little more complex with your database or tracking the user. Not sure how this has had two upvotes though as it is unclear what they are asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you right it sounds like you want to style a visited link when it is hovered/active. If so you can achieve this by combining pseudo-selectors (eg. `a:visited:hover`)

Here's a jsfiddle to illustrate the point: http://jsfiddle.net/fh79LLo0/

If this isn't what you're looking for can you maybe provide a bit more information about what you're trying to do?