# Why has this link turned purple and lost its styling properties?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to style this button so that the text is white, with a white border like the other social media buttons. The code I used for all these buttons is identical and the button has the desired properties when I preview the HTML , but for some reason when I upload the file and visit the site ([josholadunni.com](https://josholadunni.com)) the button for LinkedIn is purple and doesn't have a border. Any help would be much appreciated!

```css
.fa {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fa:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.fa-facebook {
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
}

.fa-linkedin {
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
}

.fa-instagram {
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="socialmedia">

  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/oladunnidesign/" class="fa fa-facebook" target="_blank"></a>
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/josh-oladunni-96a893b8/" class="fa fa-linkedin" target="_blank"></a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/JoshOladunniDesign/" class=" fa fa-instagram" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Looking at the page you linked above, the CSS code for `fa-linkedin` is not in your `pagedesign.css` file (which is why your text is not white and defaulting to blue or purple). Perhaps you forgot to re-upload your CSS?

Comment: @crazymatt Hi, thanks for replying - I see what you mean, but I have uploaded it - just did it again to be sure and nothing has changed. Do you know what could be causing this? It's probably something really stupid

Comment: already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188060/how-to-make-link-not-change-color-after-visited/8188105

Comment: @IvicaPesovski Thank you but I don't think that is the problem; I've tried using the text decoration and color properties, but they don't work.

Comment: @JoshOladunni There could be many reasons why your code is not being updated depending on the process. Instead of trying to walk through all senerios I suggest you try to make a simple change to see if you are able to even update your CSS. (so like add a simple comment then check on your site to see if its there). Also I see this error in your log `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - themes.css`

Answer (score 0):

Links have a psuedo-element called `:visited` that applies some default styles after you've visited the URL they point to. You should apply your styles not only to `.fa`, but also to `.fa:visited` to get the result you want.