# How to perform hover and make link not change colour when clicked in HTML

Tags: html, styles

I am using `Python` to work with `HTML` files. I exported my `dataframes` as `HTML` files and generated a clickable Table of contents. There is only one problem when I click a link in the table of contents, the colour changes. Is there a way to make it so this doesn't happen?

```
html = "</head> <body> <h1>Data records</h1> <h2>From February 2019 to January 2020</h2> </body></html>"

for link, names in zip(sorted(df, key=lambda x: int(x.split('-')[0])), data_list):         
     html += '<a href="%s">%s</a><br>' % (link, names)

with open("test.html", "w") as f:
     f.write(html)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but python doesn't really let you *click* on anything. And python doesn't really generate it unless you tell it to. And all `<a>...</a>` links will change color after you click on them in the web browser. Doesn't have anything to do with Python. You probably want to add [CSS to handle these things](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp) in your HTML.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make link not change color after visited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188060/how-to-make-link-not-change-color-after-visited)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Python, so I corrected the tags in this post. Because how you generate the HTML has very little to do with how the HTML behaves. So this question is more related to "how do I work with CSS" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried adding a css tag into your html output ?
for example :

```
html = "<style type='text/css'>a:visited{color:black;}</style></head><body> <h1>Data records</h1> <h2>From February 2019 to January 2020</h2> </body></html>"
```

Comment: Technically, this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I have less than 50 reputation, I can't comment the others yet..

Comment: That's fine, but that is starting to look like a proper answer to me :) Well done and a good edit! You probably want to refer to `a:visited` as well/instead, as this is probably causing the color to change when clicked (not hover)

Comment: Does that mean I need to create a CSS file?

Comment: yes, I mean visited. Hover was just if its also possible as well

Comment: @Pythonista This is valid HTML: https://gist.github.com/Torxed/f89bbf9762d2e2467cb7c8cdcec60972, meaning there's no need to create a separate CSS file. Altho it's usually prefered for readability's sake.

Comment: It is called "embedded css" you can do the same with js, for example.

Comment: Thank you so much for the insights